# Generate assembly files by -S option while building Linux kernel

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-kernel, cross-compiling

I'm trying to generate assembly files for Linux kernel while cross compiling it to ARM architecture. 
I tried to generate mmap.s file by ;

```
 make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- CFLAGS='-S' mm/mmap.o
```

But no assembly file generated. I tried editing `HOSTCFLAGS` section by adding `-S` option. Then the compilation fails. When I added `'-Wa,-alh=$<.s'` still mmap.s was not generated.

Any suggestion on how to solve this issue?

Comment: It's a good question, I presume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use:
`make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- mm/mmap.s`

(please note `.s` in the end of the command).

Comment: How to generate all .s files when building the kernel, except for just 1 file?